Mirror external display by default
In ubuntu 22.04, on connecting an external display, it 'joins the displays' by default. This collapses windows from all workspaces into a single workspace, and so I would like it to mirror by default.
Is there a way to do this? Or alternatively, is there a way to disable joining displays?
(I'm using the Workspace Matrix gnome extension to arrange the workspaces in 2D)
